# What is the purpose of body:before when setting background image?

Tags: css

What is the purpose of using

```
body:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
    background-image: url("images/bgimage.jpg");
}
```

instead of

```
body {
    background-image: url("images/bgimage.jpg");
}
```

They both look the same to me in a basic example.

Comment: the first one make it fixed ... you can see the difference when you will have scroll on content .. so make the content big enough and you will see

Comment: Why not use `background-attachment: fixed` ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif It appears that you are correct. Adding more content to the HTML shows the difference. I was googling hard, but I couldn't find the answer.

Comment: One difference I can see it that the first CSS, with its absolute positioning and `z-index: 0`, makes the contents of the body invisible. If I correct that, there is no difference between it and a background on `body` with `fixed`. See https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/emnjxko6/3/ vs https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/emnjxko6/4/